# How to build request handler class in lambda function for a Springboot CRUD Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, yaml

I am trying to invoke a lambda function by the new feature - function URL"S https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html using which I don't require any trigger events.

I am able to get the output for a simple java application using the above approach written in documentation by using Java as runtimeEnvironment and passing Jar file from my local machine.

Now, I want to test lambda functionality by same concept but for Springboot-Application which has restful endpoints for GET,POST,PUT,DELETE for different crud operations connecting with MySql db. The problem I am facing is how to tell handler class that to route to these endpoints and trigger lambda functions.

Any help/suggestions appreciated here. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't work with this URL's feature but it allows handling Lambda events similar to standard Spring web requests.

You can check this one: https://github.com/MelonProjectCom/lambda-http-router

Example usage:

```java
@PathPostMapping("/example/test")
public String example(@Body String body) {
    return "Hello World! - body: " + body;
}
```